# Custom Search Query in relation to search form

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've got some custom fields as meta data for a new post type - Properties (for an estate agents), so want to search by number of bedrooms, min/max value and location. I have a form with multiple drop-downs for each of these fields:

location, min_value, max_value, bedrooms

Also, I have meta boxes on the posts themselves, so one for price, bedrooms, location, and a taxonomy type of property_type - rent, sale, and commerical.

I've found this piece of code online but not sure how to manipulate it so it takes whatever value the form takes?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'location',
            'value' => '[LOCATION HERE]',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => '[PRICE HERE FROM FORM]',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Also, I understand the search query goes on function.php but do I call it from where the form is, or where the results are outputted? ie. my homepage or my searchpage?

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'Properties',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'location',
        'value' => '[LOCATION HERE]',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'min_value',
        'value' => '[min value here]',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
    array(
        'key' => 'max_value',
        'value' => '[max value here]',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
    array(
        'key' => 'bedrooms',
        'value' => '[bedroom here]',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
  )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and You have to call this in your `searchpage`....

Comment: Hi, so how does it take the value of your form? Say if your form field id was 'bedrooms' does that become the 'value' of the search array?

Comment: you have to use form field `name` not `id`.

Comment: So the name of your form matches the key of the array and thats how they are linked?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help Yogesh, I modified your answer to get this which seems to work:

```
            <?php $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'Property',
                    'property_type'=>$_GET['type'],
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => '_property_info_location',
                            'value' => Cuztom::uglify($_GET['location']),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => '_property_info_bedrooms',
                            'value' => $_GET['bedrooms'],
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => '_property_info_price',
                            'value' => $_GET['max_value'],
                            'compare' => '<=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => '_property_info_price',
                            'value' => $_GET['min_value'],
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                        ),
                    ),
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                ?>
```